# How can I gets inner function value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-function

I want to know what is the right syntax to gets the value of the `outer_function` (like the 1st printing below => **the expected result**) in python3:

```
def outer_function():
    def inner_function():
        return u'{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}'
    return inner_function


print(u'{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}')
print(outer_function())
```

The 1st printing is:
`{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}`

The 2nd printing is:
`<function outer_function.<locals>.inner_function at 0x7f1bf20e0dc0>`

Comment: The syntax is `()`. You just call the returned function to get its result.

Comment: `print(outer_function()())`

Comment: Since you particularly said "Python3", that `u""` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should return inner_function() instead of inner_function.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-invoking-functions-with-and-without-parentheses/

```
def outer_function():
    def inner_function():
        return u'{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}'
    return inner_function()


print(u'{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}')
print(outer_function())
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently what returns from the `outer_function` is the reference to the `inner_function`. The value you're looking for is the return value of the `inner_function`, so you need to call it too.

```py
def outer_function():
    def inner_function():
        return '{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}'

    return inner_function


print(outer_function()())
```

Or:

```py
def outer_function():
    def inner_function():
        return '{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}'

    return inner_function


inner = outer_function()
print(inner)   # same output as you got.
print(inner())
```

You could also return the return value of the `inner_function` within the `outer_function` itself:

```py
def outer_function():
    def inner_function():
        return '{"f1":["x1", "y1", "z1"], "f2":["x2", "y2", "y3"]}'

    return inner_function()

print(outer_function())
```